# vi script problem on autocmd

Tags: vim

I want to create a template for all my python scripts using this

```
autocmd bufnewfile *.py so ~/.vim/templates/python_skeleton.txt
```

the content of python_sekleton.txt is as simple as this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print 'Hello World'
```

but vi give error message when i start to edit a new python script:

```
line    2:
E488: Trailing characters: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
line    4:
E488: Trailing characters: print 'Hello World'
```

it seems '#' is not escaped,and anyone can work it out?thanks i advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to read the file, not source/execute it.

So use something like the following instead:

```
autocmd bufnewfile *.py :r ~/.vim/templates/python_skeleton.txt
```

Comment: Thanks.This is what i ask for.But vim seems to add a total new line at the begin of the new python file i am try to begin editing.Any idea of what happened this time?

Comment: Try:

    autocmd bufnewfile *.py :0r ~/.vim/templates/python_skeleton.txt

The "0" inserts the text at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `so` command sources a file of `Ex` commands, **not** directly a Python file.  You need to use `pyf` instead of `so` to execute a Python file.

Comment: Thanks also.pyf try to execute the python file.but :r is what I really want.It don't matter.